# Is there an error in Zorich concerning Cartesian product and power set axiom?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am reading "Analysis" by Zorich and I think there is an error in the chapter 1.4.2, "Axioms for Set Theory". In this chapter, an ordered pair is defined as $(X,Y):=\{\{X,X\},\{X,Y\}\}$. After introducing the Power set axiom which says "For any set $X$ there exists a set $\mathcal{P}(X)$ having each subset of $X$ as an element, and having no other elements", the author wrote:

> We can now verify that the ordred pairs $(x,y)$, where $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$, really do form a set, namely
>   $$ X\times Y:=\{p\in\mathcal{P}\left(\mathcal{P}(X)\cup\mathcal{P}(Y)\right)\mid \left(p=(x,y)\right)\land (x\in X)\land(y\in Y)\}.$$

I think it should be $$ X\times Y:=\{p\in\mathcal{P}\left(\mathcal{P}(X)\cup\mathcal{P}(X\cup Y)\right)\mid \left(p=(x,y)\right)\land (x\in X)\land(y\in Y)\},$$
because in general the set $\mathcal{P}(X)\cup\mathcal{P}(Y)$ does not contain the element $\{x,y\}$.

Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are quite right. Of course $\mathcal P(X)\cup\mathcal P(X\cup Y)=\mathcal P(X\cup Y)$ since $\mathcal P(X)\subseteq\mathcal P(X\cup Y).$
Perhaps they intended to write
$$X\times Y:=\{p\in\mathcal P(\mathcal P(X\cup Y))|(p=(x,y))\land(x\in X)\land(y\in Y)\}$$
though I would prefer to write
$$X\times Y:=\{p\in\mathcal P(\mathcal P(X\cup Y))|\exists x\exists y(p=(x,y))\land(x\in X)\land(y\in Y)\}.$$